# not able make any changes while flashing the ROM with RSA tool of lenovo

Tags: android, bootloader, android-firmware

I'm able to flash the ROM with the original copy of firmware in Lenovo *TB-7504X* but not able to do it with any other ROM and even not able to change the *logo.bin* file, i also changed the *CHECKSUM* accordingly but it is failing every time if i make changes.

fastboot mode is not supported so can't change ROM with adb, tool I'm using is RSA ( Rescue and Smart Assistant ).

also tried to change the firmware with SP_Flash_Tool_V5 but didn't work.

what do i need to do if i want to change logo or anything else in firmware ?

*chip-set: MT6737M*

Comment: This question seems to be about how to use software, not how to create it, so I have voted to close the question.  There are other sites where you can ask how to administer you machine, eg https://superuser.com/